# What is a schema manager in Spring's Hibernate and how I set it?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Some tables were dropped at development environment during a `spring-data-jpa` project test and the developer responsible for it said it only used `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`. Checking [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-hbmddl), I suspected he had it set as `create-drop`, but since he said he didn't use, I went for [this piece of information](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization.using-hibernate):

> Spring Boot chooses a default value for you based on whether it thinks your database is embedded.
> It defaults to create-drop if no schema manager has been detected

Since his application actually managed to connect to our development environment PostgreSQL database (since it dropped some tables), I start to think he maybe could have forgotten to set `hbm2ddl.auto` and automatically it went as `create-drop`.

Is it possible to connect to PostgreSQL and don't have a valid schema manager defined? Which are the most common schema managers?

PS: at this application `@DataSource` is set this way:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setUrl(someUrlConnectionStringFromApplicationDotPropertiesFile);
    return dataSource;
}
```

like `String someUrlConnectionStringFromApplicationDotPropertiesFile = "jdbc:postgresql://ipAddress:port/dbName?user=user&password=pass"`. I know `spring-data-jpa` sets everything with spring jpa properties automatically without this method, this is currently an unchangeable legacy code :(

Comment: I haven't found the answer to this question yet, but there is quite a lot of information about schema initialization here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-data-sql-and-schema-sql

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot said they are Higher-level Database Migration Tool (Flyway or Liquibase).
ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.x/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-access.jpa-properties, https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.x/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-access.jpa-properties

You can also configure them through Spring Boot documentation or their own docs. ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.x/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization.migration-tool

For example, configure Flyway community version through maven (https://flywaydb.org/download/community):

```
<build>
    ...
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>9.12.0</version>
    </plugin>
    ...
</build>
```